# in Python, how can you merge using datetime as condition (not exact but with some time diff)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, merge

I have two dataframes

```
left = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10, datetime(2020, 5, 17, 20, 12, 28)],\
                 ['B', 15, datetime(2020, 5, 17, 16, 22, 45)],\
                 ['C', 20, datetime(2020, 5, 17, 12, 45, 12)],\
                 ['D', 25, datetime(2020, 5, 17, 13, 57, 44)]],\
                columns = ['Letter_l', 'Int_l', 'Datetime_l'])
```

and

```
right = pd.DataFrame([['A', 20, datetime(2020, 5, 17, 20, 12, 35)],\
                  ['B', 30, datetime(2020, 5, 17, 18, 45, 25)],\
                  ['C', 40, datetime(2020, 5, 17, 12, 45, 20)],\
                  ['D', 50, datetime(2020, 5, 17, 18, 16, 44)]],\
                columns = ['Letter_r', 'Int_r', 'Datetime_r'])
```

I want to join by two of the three columns: `Letter` and `Datetime`.
For datetime I am not looking for an exact match, but for a maximal difference of 10 seconds for the right dataframe.

I know how to join with normal conditions:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(left=left, right=right, how='left',\
                     left_on=['Letter_l'], right_on=['Letter_r'])
```

but the output I am looking for is:

```
|-----|--------------|-----------|--------------------|--------------|-----------|--------------------|
|     |   Letter_l   |   Int_l   |     datetime_l     |   Letter_r   |   Int_r   |     datetime_r     | 
|-----|--------------|-----------|--------------------|--------------|-----------|--------------------|
|  0  |      A       |     10    | 2020-05-17 20:12:28|      A       |     20    | 2020-05-17 20:12:35|
|  1  |      C       |     20    | 2020-05-17 12:45:12|      C       |     40    | 2020-05-17 12:45:20|
|-----|--------------|-----------|--------------------|--------------|-----------|--------------------|
```

Can this be done using standard `pd.merge`?

Of course I could try using `sqlite3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform an `asof` merge with [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) on `DateTime` with a tolerance of `10` seconds:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(left.sort_values('Datetime_l'),
                   right.sort_values('Datetime_r'),
                   left_by='Letter_l', right_by='Letter_r',
                   left_on='Datetime_l', right_on='Datetime_r',
                   direction='nearest', tolerance=pd.Timedelta(seconds=10))\
       .dropna(subset=['Letter_r'])
```

Result:

```
  Letter_l  Int_l          Datetime_l Letter_r  Int_r          Datetime_r
0        C     20 2020-05-17 12:45:12        C   40.0 2020-05-17 12:45:20
3        A     10 2020-05-17 20:12:28        A   20.0 2020-05-17 20:12:35
```

Comment: @agustin happy coding :)